# The ambiguity is on a relation between User and UserLeague

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma

I've got two types: User and UserLeague

```
type User {
    id: ID! @unique
    email: String! @unique
    password: String!
    name: String!
    predictions: [Prediction!]!
    leagues: [UserLeague!]! @relation(name: "MemberOfLeague")
    ownedLeagues: [UserLeague!]! @relation(name: "LeagueOwner")
}
type UserLeague {
    id: ID! @unique
    passcode: String!
    name: String!
    history: [Prediction!]!
    users: [User!]! @relation(name: "MemberOfLeague")
    owner: User! @relation(name: "LeagueOwner")
}
```

Which to me looks an awful lot like it's analogous to the example in the prisma docs here https://www.prismagraphql.com/docs/reference/service-configuration/data-modelling-(sdl)-eiroozae8u#the-@relation-directive with the `User` and `Story` types.

But when I try to deploy with `yarn prisma deploy`, I get the following error message:

> "message": "There is a relation ambiguity during the migration. Please first name the old relation on your schema. The ambiguity is on a relation between User and UserLeague."

I don't quite see what I'm missing. Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: I tried running "prisma deploy" on a brand new project using your types (minus the [Prediction] type which you didn't list here), and it successfully deployed.
I am on Prisma version 1.8.3

Comment: I had a similar issue just now and what happened is I had renamed a field as well as adding new fields.  When I undid the new additions and just had the first rename and ran deploy it worked, and then I added my new fields and ran deploy and it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the deployment history of the schema you posted, it is hard to say with certainty what the problem is.  However, it seems you are trying to deploy schema changes without specifying enough information in the `relation` directive (for example, I don't see any specification of `onDelete` instructions).  Without this, `prisma` will throw the 'ambiguous relation' message.

The reason for this is described [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/service-configuration/data-model/data-modelling-(sdl)-eiroozae8u#migrating-the-value-of-a-scalar-field).  To summarize, it comes down to adding enough info to the SDL schema so that you get leverage `prisma` migrating your DB every time you run `prisma deploy`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Enter `prisma delete` to delete the service, and then enter `prisma deploy`.

That solved the problem for me.